# Issue with inserting value in treeview cell (at a particular row and column) tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am using the following code to insert value in treeview cell at a particular row and column value:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox

root = tk.Tk()

# Label
ttk.Label(root, text = "App Label",
          font = ("Calibri bold", 20), foreground = 'darkblue').grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = (10, 5), pady = (5, 0), sticky='', columnspan = 2)

# define columns
columns = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings', height = 120)

# define headings
tree.column("1", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=185, stretch=False)
tree.heading('1', text='B 1')
tree.column("2", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=185, stretch=False)
tree.heading('2', text='B 2')
tree.column("3", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=185, stretch=False)
tree.heading('3', text='B 3')
tree.column("4", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=185, stretch=False)
tree.heading('4', text='B 4')
tree.column("5", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=185, stretch=False)
tree.heading('5', text='B 5')

tree.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky='NSEW', padx = 20, pady = (20, 20))

tree.set(1, 'B1', '1')  ## Here I want to some random value '1' in row 1 and col 'B1'

root.mainloop()
```

After running the above code I am getting following error "TclError: Item 1 not found" in line `tree.set(1, cols[0], '1')`.

After the suggestion by @acw1668, I have added the following before `tree.set(1, cols[0], '1')`:

```
tree_init_df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((12, 5), dtype = np.str))
for index, row in tree_init_df.iterrows():
    tree.insert("", tk.END, text=index, values=list(row))
```

But still I am same error.

Can someone let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: You cannot update a cell of an empty treeview.

Comment: The row is identified by *row ID* which is returned by `tree.insert(...)`, not an integer index.